# Update UI on OKHTTP network call without RXJava

Tags: android, networking, mvp, okhttp

I have a network call in a model class. In `runOnUIThread` I want to be able to update the UI, but I don't want to have to pass in a reference to anything in the UI, into my networking class. How can I still update the UI, without giving the networking class a reference to the UI class and without using a library like RXJava?

Here is the code I'm working with.

public class WeatherNetwork {

```
public CurrentWeather getDailyWeather(float lat, float lng) {
    String URL = "";
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(URL)
            .build();

    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {

            try {
                String jsonData = response.body().string();
                final String passingData = jsonData;

                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch(JSONException e) {
                Log.d(ACTIVITY + " JSONEXCEPTION", e.getMessage());
            } catch(IOException e){
                Log.d(ACTIVITY + " IOEXCEPTION", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    return new CurrentWeather();
}
```

}

Comment: Use an event bus (e.g., greenrobot's EventBus). Or, use a reactive programming approach (e.g., RxJava, `LiveData` from the Architecture Components).

Comment: Any way to not do it with a library?

Comment: You are already using a library (OkHttp), so I am unclear why you are opposed to libraries. You are welcome to do some sort of callback thing yourself, but indirectly a callback will pass a reference to the UI. I do not know where you are drawing the line for what is and is not passing a reference to the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the `Callback` as the method parameter.

```
public void getDailyWeather(float lat, float lng, Callback callback) {
```

When you enqueue, give that.

```
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(callback);
    return; // This method is done now. Make it void
    // You cannot return from a async method
}
```

Then, elsewhere,

```
float lat = 0;
float lng = 0;
api.getDailyWeather(lat, lng, new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {

        try {
            String jsonData = response.body().string();
            final String passingData = jsonData;

            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // This is still necessary
                        // But you can now access Views from your UI class   
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch(JSONException e) {
            Log.d(ACTIVITY + " JSONEXCEPTION", e.getMessage());
        } catch(IOException e){
            Log.d(ACTIVITY + " IOEXCEPTION", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

---

If you want to clean that up, you can define your own callback, for example

```
public interface CurrentWeatherCallback {
   void onWeatherDataReceived(CurrentWeather weather);
}
```

Then keep what you have, but use the other callback

```
 final CurrentWeather weather = new CurrentWeather();
 // TODO: Parse JSON 

 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       if (callback != null) callback.onWeatherDataReceived(weather);
    }
  });
```

Either way, you are passing interfaces, not a reference to any direct UI element